# Pass class Constructor through template argument in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, initializer-list

I know function can pass through `template` argument, can I pass class Constructor like this.

**Update:**
The whole reason that I want to do this, is I can choose constructor in memory pool and without any code changing in the class I want to alloc (in this case `class A`)

```c
class A
{
public:
  A(){n=0;}
  explicit A(int i){n=i;}

private:
  int n;
};

class MemoryPool
{
public:
   void* normalMalloc(size_t size);
   template<class T,class Constructor>
   T* classMalloc();
};

template<class T,class Constructor>
T* MemoryPool::classMalloc()
{
   T* p = (T*)normalMalloc(sizeof(T));
   new (p) Constructor; // choose constructor
   return p;
}

MemoryPool pool;
pool.classMalloc<A,A()>(); //get default class
pool.classMalloc<A,A(1)>();
```

Comment: `A()` in a template argument denotes a function type, taking no argument and returning `A`.

Comment: Could you please provide some more context? Given only this little information, I'd ask myself: why not use `new A()` directly instead of `new_func<A, A()>`? To put it another way, what does `new_func` buy you? Does it abstract away construction?

Comment: @Andre The reason is I want to use it in the memory pool that I can malloc a class with choosing construction

Comment: Would you be satisfied if you could type `pool.classMalloc<A>();` and `pool.classMalloc<A>(1);` ? That would actually be quite easy to do.

Comment: But for memory pool the argument of the malloc class constructor is unknown.

Comment: @michael911009 Have you read the C++ FAQ about placement new [http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10] and memory pools [http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.14]? Seems like it could be useful for you.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot pass around constructors, but you can pass around factory functors:

```
class A
{
    int n;

    A(int i) : n(i) {};

public:

    static A* makeA(int i)
    {
        return new A(i);
    }
};

template<typename T, typename Factory>
T* new_func(Factory factory)
{
    return factory();
}

#include <functional>

int main()
{
    new_func<A>(std::bind(&A::makeA, 0));
    new_func<A>(std::bind(&A::makeA, 1));
}
```

Comment: The whole reason that I want to do this, is I can choose constructor in memory pool and without any code changing in the class I want to alloc

Answer (score 4):

Your whole assumption is wrong. You don't need that feature.

```
template<class T>
T* new_func()
{
   return new T;
}
```

The thing after `new` is a type, not a constructor reference.

Comment: What about the difference between `new A()` and `new A(1)`

Comment: That doesn't "pass a constructor". That would pass a complete argument list. That doesn't even work for normal (member) function pointer template arguments. You have to pass that as normal function arguments instead of as template arguments, of course. Read or ask about "perfect forwarding".

Comment: Add a parameter to `new_func()`: `T* new_func(int i = 0)` and pass it on to constructor.

Comment: The whole reason that I want to do this, is I can choose constructor in memory pool and without any code changing in the class I want to alloc

Comment: @michael911009, are you allowed to use C++11? It has some features that might be very useful. In short, you want to be able to type something like `pool.classMalloc<ANY_TYPE>(any_arguments_that_can_construct_that_type)`, don't you?

Comment: C++0x is satisfy, but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

This way better I think

```
template<class T, int n>
struct Factory
{
  static T* new_func()
  {
     return new T(n);
  }
};

template<class T>
struct Factory<T,0>
{
  static T* new_func()
  {
     return new T;
  }
};

T* t = Factory<T>::new_func(); //call default constructor
T* t2 = Factory<T,2>::new_func(); //call constructor T(2)
```

Comment: The whole reason that I want to do this, is I can choose constructor in memory pool and without any code changing in the class I want to alloc

Comment: You can use the Factory style in your Memory pool class.

Comment: Is it annoying that every time I use it. I have to write a new Factory struct, since the argument of the malloc class constructor is unknown

Comment: Check my answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711542/call-constructor-of-template-parameter